# Whether I can send some messages to a remote phone using socket programming in Android?

Tags: android, sockets

I Want to send a message to a remote Android using socket programming ..Whether it's possible? Whether they can have different IP addresses? or Whether they need to have the same IP address?

I read the below article..It says  that "the port numbers have to be the same in addition to the IP address"

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

My server is 121.xxx.xxx.xxx 
My client is 122.xxx.xxx.xxx

And server and client are androids ..Whether I will be able to send the messages from server to client? without any intermediate server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open up server sockets in Java (Dalvik). If you want a client to communicate with the server the client needs to know the server's address. That's what the article is trying to say with "the port numbers have to be the same in addition to the IP address".

Comment: My server is 121.xxx.xxx.xxx

My client is 122.xxx.xxx.xxx

Whether I will be able to send the messages from server to client?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding and my experience, You can connect to only Ipaddress of server in which ur device will act as client and any server on internet will act as server socket.Device to device connection thru socket is not possible. If you want to connect and send messages then u will have some intermediate server between devices which will act as server and client both.